# Export to a string with sc sdshow mslldp

Tags: cmd, windows-10

I want to set the output in a string from this windows command in evelated command `sc sdshow mslldp` but get only the first entry. Have anyone an idea?

Have already this:

```
C:\TMP>FOR /F "tokens=*" %a in ('test.cmd') do SET OUTPUT=%a
C:\TMP>SET OUTPUT=C:\TMP>sc sdshow mslldp
C:\TMP>SET OUTPUT=D:(D;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BG)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SO)(A;;LCRPWP;;;S-1-5-80-3141615172-2057878085-1754447212-2405740020-3916490453)
```

And now I want to add an own `(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)` parameter with `sc sdset mslldp`.

Comment: Microsoft think, that this steps would help:  To do this, follow these steps:

Open an administrative Command Prompt window, and then run the following command to check the current permissions:

Console: sc sdshow mslldp

Copy the output string from step 1, append it with (A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU), and then run the following command to add the access permission to Mslldp.dll: